# How to install PhpPgAdmin in AppServ?

Tags: php, postgresql, appserver, phppgadmin

How can i install phppgadmin in appserver on windows. I installed postgresql exe file and configures php.ini file and extracted PhpPgAdmin in www folder, but it showing php not congifured error.

Comment: Some more information would be welcome: php.ini contents, a quote of the error your actually getting, what you've already tried to do about it, version of Windows/PostgreSQL/PHP/PhpPgAdmin, etc.

Comment: php5, postgresql 9.1, windows xp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266639/postgresql-phppgadmin-in-xammp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266639/postgresql-phppgadmin-in-xammp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Installation of phppgadmin**

1) download ***postgresql-9.1.4-1-windows.exe***' (for windows), ***phpPgAdmin-5.0.4.zip***.(choose latest one)

2) install postgresql .exe file

3) extract phppgadmin in C:\Appserv\  (ex:- C:\Appserv\phpPgAdmin)

4)in php.ini file uncomment the following lines.

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

5) restart system and login into postgresql in programs.